How to avoid phantom text results displayed from Azure speech-to-text via mic audio?
I have C# code that does speech-to-text and machine translation using microphone input audio via Azure Cognitive Services. We have multiple instances of this app running (one instance for each user) while users are joined in a Web meeting. The language identification, speech-to-text, and machine translation results are fine for those utterances that are actually spoken by users. However, we often get phantom text results for the speech-to-text results even though we did not say these utterances (please see the 3 instances of erroneous in the two “Execution results” below). Any ideas on how I can avoid this phantom text? (I'd prefer not to use custom speech models if at all possible.)
Execution results for the 1st user (Tetu): Sample output in the GUI of the 1st instance of the application:
Tetu: This is sentence #1.   [Tetu’s note: This speech-to-text result is correct.]
これは文#1です。[Tetu’s note: This machine translation result into Japanese is correct.]
Tetu: This is all.   [Tetu’s note: This speech-to-text result is erroneous (is phantom text that the user did NOT say).]
以上です。
Tetu: This is sentence #2.   [Tetu’s note: This speech-to-text result is correct.]
これは文#2です。
Tetu: This is another sentence.   [Tetu’s note: This speech-to-text result is correct.]
これは別の文です。
Tetu: This meeting is called.   [Tetu’s note: This speech-to-text result is erroneous (is phantom text that the user did NOT say).]
この会議は呼び出されます。
Execution results for the 2nd user (Diana): Sample output in the GUI of the 2nd instance of the application:
Diana: This is utterance #1.   [Tetu’s note: This speech-to-text result is correct.]
これは発話#1です。
Diana: This is utterance #2.   [Tetu’s note: This speech-to-text result is correct.]
これは発話#2です。
Diana: Singapore sentence.   [Tetu’s note: This speech-to-text result is erroneous (is phantom text that the user did NOT say).]
シンガポールの文。
Diana: This meeting is for the WS adjustment.   [Tetu’s note: This speech-to-text result is correct.]
この会議はWS調整のためのものです。
Tests tried and results

Got these phantom text results while each of two users (in separate buildings) ran an instance of this application while joined in a Microsoft Teams meeting. Also confirmed we got phantom text results for a Zoom meeting. Expected: No phantom text
Tested with tissue paper wrapped and held onto the boom mic of the headsets being used by both users and the number of phantom text results tended to decrease. Phantom text also decreased when both users kept the headsets ~2 feet (60 cm) away from their mouths. (Both users used Plantronics Blackwire 3220 Series headsets.) Expected: No phantom text
Tested with the internal mic of the PCs of both users and the number of phantom text results tended to decrease. Expected: No phantom text
Programmatically decreased the mic audio recording volume (from +5.0 dB to +1.0 dB) but still got the phantom text. Also, MS Teams seemed to auto increase the recording volume back up (when we checked the recording level in Windows). Expected: No phantom text
Did not get any phantom text when running only one instance of this application. This is what we expected.

Snippet from the code being used:
public static async Task TranslationWithMicrophoneAsync_withLanguageDetectionEnabled()
{
    InitializeInPrepForEventHandlerSetup_MicAudio();

    using (var recognizerFromMicrophone = new TranslationRecognizer(TetusGlobals.config, TetusGlobals.autoDetectSourceLanguageConfig))
    {
        recognizerFromMicrophone.Recognizing += (s, e) =>
        {
            var lidResult = e.Result.Properties.GetProperty(PropertyId.SpeechServiceConnection_AutoDetectSourceLanguageResult);

            var sttResults = e.Result.Text;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sttResults))
            {
                if (lidResult == "ja-JP")
                {
                    var resultOfMT_E = e.Result.Translations["en-US"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultOfMT_E))
                    {
                        curMTresult = resultOfMT_E;
                    }
                }

                else if (lidResult == "en-US")
                {
                    var resultOfMT_J = e.Result.Translations["ja-JP"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultOfMT_J))
                    {
                        curMTresult = resultOfMT_J;
                    }
                }

                curSTTandMTresults =
                    curPersonsNameAsPrefix + ": " + sttResults + carriageReturnString + curMTresult;

                bool foundFinalSttAndMtResults = false;
                Tetu_WriteSttAndMtResults(curSTTandMTresults, foundFinalSttAndMtResults);
            }
        };

        recognizerFromMicrophone.Recognized += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.TranslatedSpeech)
            {
                var lidResult = e.Result.Properties.GetProperty(PropertyId.SpeechServiceConnection_AutoDetectSourceLanguageResult);

                var sttResults = e.Result.Text;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sttResults))
                {
                    if (lidResult == "ja-JP")
                    {
                        var resultOfMT_E = e.Result.Translations["en-US"];
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultOfMT_E))
                        {
                            curMTresult = resultOfMT_E;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (lidResult == "en-US")
                    {
                        var resultOfMT_J = e.Result.Translations["ja-JP"];
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultOfMT_J))
                        {
                            curMTresult = resultOfMT_J;
                        }
                    }

                    curSTTandMTresults =
                        curPersonsNameAsPrefix + ": " + sttResults + carriageReturnString + curMTresult;

                    bool foundFinalSttAndMtResults = true;
                    Tetu_WriteSttAndMtResults(curSTTandMTresults, foundFinalSttAndMtResults);
                }
            }
        };

        await recognizerFromMicrophone.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        do
        {
        } while (true);
    }
}

Environment or dependencies I’m using:
•   Windows 10 (Version 22H2 (OS Build 19045.5131))
•   Microsoft .NET Framework (Version 4.8.04084)
•   Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 (Version 16.11.35)
•   Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK (Version 1.41.1)
•   NAudio (Version 2.2.1)

There is no "phantom" text. That implies it was unsolicited; you clearly state it was an incorrect "response". The fact the "testers" are making random comments and not working from a "script" makes the whole testing process flawed. There is no way to correlate results and look for a pattern.

Thank you Gerry for your comment. The first 4 utterances (see below) are from a "script" that the testers (my colleague and myself) read from for all tests. The remaining 2 utterances are random utterances (for extra testing). However, we would get this phantom speech-to-text result (e.g., "Tetu: This is all.") (which I did not say) even before the random utterances were spoken.
------- (This is the sequence of utterances we spoke during the testing.)
Tetu: This is sentence #1.
Diana: This is utterance #1.
Tetu: This is sentence #2.
Diana: This is utterance #2.

Speech "stuff" is mostly async; so it must buffer; implying, one needs to get a handle on the buffering process. In particular, there may be an event that signals the "spawn" of this "phantom".

"Crosstalk". What we used to listen to on "party lines".

Thank you for the additional advice. Will think about the buffering process and possible crosstalk.
